# Some error with Flutter Plugin, about auto import

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm using IDEA to develop Flutter programs.

After my latest upgrade of the Flutter plug-in, the automatic prompt for the Flutter plug-in will go wrong.

For example, when I type in Border, the plug-in will automatically prompt Border in all packages (meterial / widget....) and import automatically for me, or even repeat imports.

The same error occurred when I used VSCODE.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the Flutter plug-in, but the problem was not solved.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

[Repeat import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpp3N.png)
[Automatic prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y0wM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Flutter plugin issue and the issue exists for IntelliJ 2019(also Android Studio 3.5 beta) so needs must wait till related version released unfortunately.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/milestone/11

You can see in the link, there too many reports for auto-suggest/import features. There are also others problem probably you didn't realize yet.

Use Android Studio stable or revert your IntelliJ to 2018.3.6.

Comment: The same error can occur in VSCODE. Should I downgrade IDEA and reinstall the Flutter plug-in?

Comment: I don't use vscode, so I'm not sure about it but I can clearly say there are many problems with IntelliJ 2019 based IDE's. Yes, downgrade IntelliJ to 2018 or use Android Studio stable version and your problem will be fixed. By the way don't forget to sync your plugins with your downgraded IDE.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using AS 3.4 now. I don't have this BUG anymore.